# what exactly is the "onSoundComplete" event in jPlayer?

Tags: html, audio, node.js, html5-audio

here is demo:http://sethaldridge.com/demos/

I don't know if there is such event in html5 audio.

---

I'm trying to push stream song by song to html5 audio with node.js.

1. create file stream ->

2. write chunk(if there are clients) on 'data' event of the stream ->

3. open next file stream on 'close'(this will make a dead circle)

I dun't know when to open next file stream on server side

Answer (score 0):

It's an event used for the jplayer flash player. There's no onSoundComplete event in the HTML5 audio api. It's used with mp3 files to signal the end of the file. The closest equivalent I imagine would be the ended event which is triggered when a media resource has completed. Is it feasible to request the next resource in your ended handler from the client side?

Comment: It's not only a flash player.It also support iOS safari browser.Check it out here:http://www.jplayer.org/

Comment: jplayer isn't only flash, but the event is only part of the jplayer flash player - the "ended" event is part of html5 audio which jplayer also supports and which you would need to use on iOS

Comment: Ended works in Chrome - tested this on both Windows and Mac: http://jsfiddle.net/qRJWc/ (video is about 25 seconds long)